# What IP Address Does Power BI Use to Retrieve an OData Feed?

Tags: azure, odata, powerbi

I want to whitelist only the IP that Power BI uses to retrieve the OData feed. I have the following document, which lists all of the public IPs for Azure, but they aren't labeled. I don't really want to go through and just whitelist all of them.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41653

Which is the one used by Power BI?

Comment: I suspect that it may be distributed and not come from a single source IP and this may change over time as the power BI service is frequently evolving. Why don't you secure via authentication rather than IP?

Comment: Well I only wanted the one thing to be able to access it so I figured that IP would be very quick and easy, I'll have to do authentication if PBI doesn't have a single or defined range of public request IPs.

Comment: I believe PowerBI support basic auth relatively easy (I assume you will also use SSL) if you want OAuth etc then you may have to do some development and that is still not public AFAIK.

Comment: Well guess I'll have to get started with authentication thanks for the info.